# How to join two tables while substracting in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

First off sorry if my english isn'nt perfect as I don't speak english. 
I have a table which lists all the people in the school and in which room they are in. 
In the second table has the room number and how many people in each room. 
How can i show a table with the eoom number and the amount of empty seats in the room? 
I am using the Microsoft sqlserver managment studio 2008.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure of your tables look like this:

First table:

```
StudentId | RoomNumber
```

Second Table:

```
RoomNumber | Count
```

Then,

```
select t1.RoomNumber, t2.Count - count(t1.StudentId)
from FirstTable t1
inner join SecondTable t2
on t1.RoomNumber = t2.RoomNumber
group by t1.RoomNumber
```

Comment: Grouping by t1.RoomNumber and counting same thing will always give you 1 in count. Replace with `count(t1.StudentId)`

Answer (score 0):

Tables:

**Students**
StudentId | RoomId

**Rooms**
RoomId | NumberOfSeats

```
Select room.RoomId, room.NumberOfSeats - count(stu.StudentId)
from Rooms room
left join Students stu on room.RoomId = stu.RoomId
group by room.RoomId
```

This way you will get the rooms without any students too

Fiddle: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a61e0/1)

Answer (score -1):

```
select t1.StudentId,
    t1.RoomNumber,
    t1.StudentId-Count(t2.Count),
    t2.RoomNumber,
    t2.count
from FirstTable as t1
Right join SecondTable as t2
on t1.RoomNumber = t2.RoomNumber
group by t2.RoomNumber
```

Comment: after tables use   Aliases Word AS example  Select * From tablename As a